Get rid of unwanted padding/border around NWJS app?
My app is a frameless application. For some reason there is a 5px border around the window. I cant seam to get rid of it.
NWJS Version:
nwjs-sdk-v0.87.0-linux-x64
index.sass
html, body
    border: none
    outline: none
    padding: none

    background-color: #444
    color: #fff

    overflow: hidden

package.json
{

    "name": "atomspace.calc",
    "description": "Calculator Application",
    "main": "./RESOURCES/INDEX.html",
    "version": "00.00.01",

    "window": {
        "icon": "./RESOURCES/VISUALS/FAVICON.png",
        "title": "AtomSpace Calculator App",
        "show_in_taskbar": true,
        "position": "center",
        "transparent": false,
        "resizable": false,
        "toolbar": false,
        "frame": false,

        "width": 400,
        "min_width": 400,
        "max-width": 400,

        "height": 500,
        "min_height": 500,
        "max_height": 500
    }

}

Screenshot of problem

You should post the version of NW.js you are using and anything in the package.json that would be relevant.

I added some stuff in that might be useful. Im at a standstill right now because i cant figure out why that border is there.

Ive had this problem before and i was able to figure it out. However i cannot remember what i did to get rid of that border around the window. I can use a negative margin to make it go over that border but that is not a proper solution.

I think you just need margin: 0px.
I remember it by saying "Bumpo" which sounds like the name of a clown.
BMP0
html,
body {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

it helps that b m p is alphabetical too.
Here's what I got to work:
https://github.com/nwutils/nwutils.github.io/files/15445277/test.zip

That was exactly it! I dont know why it didn't occur to me to do that haha Thank you!
